# How to deploy a uiautomator JAR file to phone using APK

Tags: android, apk, android-uiautomator, android-install-apk

Assuming i have a uiautomator JAR file and my app will call/run the uiautomator JAR file. How can i package it in my app's APK so that the JAR will be deployed to a specific folder in the phone when i install my app by running the APK?

Comment: Your app cannot "call/run the uiautomator JAR file", except maybe on a rooted device.

Comment: yes. i'm aware of that and that is not an issue for my case.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is interested to know, i solve it by attaching my script JAR to the asset folder in the APK and use code below to re-create the file at my desired place.

```
InputStream tempIn =  assetMgr.open("UiautomationScript.jar");
int size = tempIn.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
tempIn.read(buffer);

FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/UiautomationScript.jar");
OutputStream tempOut = new FileOutputStream("/data/local/tmp/UiautomationScript.jar");
tempOut.write(buffer, 0, size);
tempIn.close();
```

Comment: Did you put the above code in onCreate part of the App?

Comment: I don't understand fully can you elaborate more. Is this an android app/apk that you have build to trigger the test suite. I have written my test suite using python wrapper of uiautomator(https://github.com/openatx/uiautomator2). How do I deploy my python script. If the python script is building some jar file somewhere, what is the path to it.